# What is the difference between proxy and reify?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between proxy and reify? I have some example code:

```
(.listFiles (java.io.File. ".")
  (proxy
    [java.io.FileFilter] []
    (accept [f]
      (.isDirectory f))))

(.listFiles (java.io.File. ".")
  (reify
    java.io.FileFilter
    (accept [this f]
      (.isDirectory f))))
```

the result is same, when use proxy or reify, what is better?

**Update:**

I found something:

- proxy no need the `this` as first parameter.
- proxy support superclass.
- proxy support arguments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [Clojure.org's overview of data types](http://clojure.org/datatypes):

> The method bodies of `reify` are lexical closures, and can refer to the surrounding local scope. `reify` differs from `proxy` in that:
>
> - Only protocols or interfaces are supported, no concrete superclass.
> - The method bodies are true methods of the resulting class, not external fns.
> - Invocation of methods on the instance is direct, not using map lookup.
> - No support for dynamic swapping of methods in the method map.
>
> The result is better performance than `proxy`, both in construction and invocation. `reify` is preferable to `proxy` in all cases where its constraints are not prohibitive.

Source: http://clojure.org/datatypes